# JSON returns multiple values with the same name

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm a bit new to this, so don't be too hard on me despite the fact that I probably sound like a noob.

I have a JSON source that I'm pulling from with the following JS code:

```
$.getJSON("http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singleorderdata&marketid=14",   function(data)
```

That gives me an output that looks like the following:

```
{
    "price": "0.00008926",
    "quantity": "304.08451708",
    "total": "0.02714258"
}, {
    "price": "0.00008927",
    "quantity": "107.68391178",
    "total": "0.00961295"
}
```

Which I set to a var "result".

Because there are multiple "price" values, I don't know how to just use the first one. Any ideas on how I could do this?

I'm using Node.js and jQuery just for reference.

Comment: The returned value must be an array. To use the first one, do it like result[0].price

Comment: Looking at the given url, you would use `result.sellorders[0]` to access the first item

Comment: Thanks guys! Appreciate it! Got the code to work :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON structure actually looks like this:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "return": {
        "WDC": {
            "marketid": "14",
            "label": "WDC\/BTC",
            "primaryname": "WorldCoin",
            "primarycode": "WDC",
            "secondaryname": "BitCoin",
            "secondarycode": "BTC",
            "sellorders": [{
                "price": "0.00007760",
                "quantity": "2.79222406",
                "total": "0.00021668"
            }, {
                "price": "0.00007761",
                "quantity": "933.65491273",
                "total": "0.08358597"
            }, {
                "price": "0.00007842",
                "quantity": "7.39656299",
                "total": "0.00058004"
            }, ... and so on ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

---

Because the JSON is parsed automatically for you, all you need to do is work with it like normal objects.

```
console.log(result["return"].WDC.sellorders[0]);
```

---

I used `["return"]` instead of `.return` because some older browsers will trip over the latter.

To iterate the `sellorders` Array, you'd use a `for` statement, or `.forEach()`.